# How to pass function as parameter with multiline array in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript

Suppose I have this function in coffeescript file

```
test = (arr, fn) ->
    console.log item for item in arr
    fn()
```

Here is how I call it

```
test [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ->
    console.log "start"
    # function body
    console.log "finish"
```

Everything OK until array become too long and I want split it on several lines. Like this

```
test ["first element here",
      "second element here",
      "third element here",
      "fourth element here",
      "fifth element here"], ->
    console.log "start"
    # function body
    console.log "finish"
```

This is valid since coffeescript compiler compiles it exactly how I expect, but IDEA says that there is **Unexpected indent** at `console.log "start"` line. I press *Ctrl+Alt+L* and IDEA gives me this

```
test ["first element here",
      "second element here",
      "third element here",
      "fourth element here",
      "fifth element here"], ->
console.log "start"
# function body
console.log "finish"
```

which is wrong, since in that case empty function is passed as parameter. Is this a bug or I can fix it by myself?

Comment: I think you should report it to the intellij coffeescript plugin team :)

Comment: yep, I already openned an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains' support told me that it's a bug, so I openned an [issue here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7767).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll have to indent the function body a little bit more to make it work:

```
test ["first element here",
      "second element here",
      "third element here",
      "fourth element here",
      "fifth element here"], ->
       console.log "start"
       # function body
       console.log "finish"
#      ^ This column is indented two from the start of the array
#    ^ Array starts here
```

At least that works for me in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Vitalii I thought you wanted a workaround for the **Unexpected indent** as an answer as well.

Comment: I use clean up feature a lot and in this case I can't use it because it breaks my code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug on the CoffeeScript IDEA plugin as user1737909 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495776/how-to-pass-function-as-parameter-with-multiline-array-in-idea#comment23677653_16495776).

But if you want to solve this right now, i'd recommend to just use a variable for the array and move on:

```
arr = [
  "first element here"
  "second element here"
  "third element here"
  "fourth element here"
  "fifth element here"
]

test arr, ->
  console.log "start"
  # function body
  console.log "finish"
```

Comment: That's just a hack, not real solution

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov, doesn't it solve the problem of IDEA complaining about the code? Besides, i wouldn't call making the code easier to read (both for humans _and_ IDEs it seems) a hack, but to each its own =P